# How to use ref and other fields in the request body?

Tags: swagger, openapi

My use case in the root level json there are 100 fields and out of those 100 fields 90 fields are common and the remaining 10 fields varies for different API's, I need to specify this 90 fields in a global space and on top of that I need to put the 10 different fields

SAMPLE

POST localhost:3000/api/v1/people
{
name: "", age: "", father_name: ""
//other 90 fields
}

POST localhost:3000/api/v1/student
{
//all fields of people and the below fields.
department_name:"", courses_enroled: ""
}

POST localhost:3000/api/v1/teacher
{
//all fields of people and the below fields.
yoe: "", //assume some specific fields
}

I need to define people payload in global space and in student API, I need to ref it.

How to do this in swagger.
whenever I use **ref**, it replaces al other fields in the same level.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend existing definition in Swagger 3 and higher (not sure which version you are using). Example in yaml (not sure what you use):

```yaml
definitions:
            Response:
                description: "Response Object"
                type: object
                properties:
                    success:
                        description: "If action was successful or not"
                        type: boolean
                        example: true
                    message:
                        description: "Action message"
                        type: string
                        example: "Some message"
                    data:
                        description: "Response data"
                        type: Any
                        nullable: true
            ErrorResponse:
                allOf:
                    - $ref: "#/definitions/Response"
                    - type: object
                      properties:
                          success:
                              example: false
                          message:
                              example: "Error message"
                          data:
                              example: null
```